# Bevel problem at intersection

Tags: modeling, bevel

After hours of trying I still don´t get why the bevel doesnt work the way I want it to.
[image]
[image]
When I bevel this edge for some reason it does weird things at the intersection instead of simply beveling with a clear cut there.

[image]
[image]
Eventually I want to Bevel all the edges but when I do that I get this weird shading, best seent on the top left corner, and I have no idea how to clean that topology up.

I have normalized and applied all tramsforms.

Please someone help, this is really frustrating and demotivating since this doesnt make any sense to me :(

Comment: Have you checked Face Orientation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's the way bevel works, if it gives bad topology, you can bevel twice then rework the topology to make it look good:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I actually pretty much fixed this by changing the "Miter Outer" to Arc.
[image]
This introduces now a new shading problem where you can see weird lines.
[image]
Adding geometry to make quads just made the lines appear elsewhere.
[image]
[image]
As this has been the solution to most of my problems, I don´t know what I could do here.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I have now found a solution for this shading issue. First use the Knifetool as follows.
[image]
Connect the verts to make quads.
[image]
slide the new verts in close by selecting them and press g two times and dragging.
[image]
[image]